# K8s with docker hub

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, dockerhub

I have configured jenkins with github.com. Jenkins notices if commit occurs and then jenkins make the docker image and upload the new image to docker hub. How can I make k8s listens to docker hub i.e. k8s notices the change in docker hub and then creates a new deployment. What tool should be used?

Answer (score 0):

You can't on the fly, but you can build a system around Docker hub if you setup a webhooks. I have build a free software for Docker Swarm auto-deployment https://github.com/pnk-sh/docker-octopus-stack

If you use software there "pull" every min. then you get in troubles with Docker Hub when you hit 5000 pull's a day.

Its required you buy a pro-account, free account will only allow you around 250 pulls a day.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to run [Jenkins agents in the k8s cluster](https://medium.com/vivid-seats-engineering/how-to-kubernetes-pods-as-jenkins-build-agents-a726d3886861). Then you could write a script that is capable of update the tag of a deployment. We use gitlab in k8s and in conjunction with helm it is possible to update and deploy the image.